# How to use @FocusedValue with optionals?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

This question is similar to [this unanswered question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653321) from the Apple Developer Forums, but with a slightly different scenario:

- I have a view with a `@FetchRequest` property of type `FetchedResults<Metric>`
- Within the view, I display the list of those objects
- I can tap on one item to select it, storing that selection in a `@State var selection: Metric? = nil` property.

Here's the properties I defined for my `@FocusedValue`:

```
struct FocusedMetricValue: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Metric?
}

extension FocusedValues {
    var metricValue: FocusedMetricValue.Value? {
        get { self[FocusedMetricValue.self] }
        set { self[FocusedMetricValue.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Here's how I set the focusedValue from my list view:

```
.focusedValue(\.metricValue, selection)
```

And here's how I'm using the `@FocusedValue` on my `Commands` struct:

```
struct MacOSCommands: Commands {

    @FocusedValue(\.metricValue) var metric

    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Metric") {
            Button("Test") {
                print(metric??.name ?? "-")
            }
            .disabled(metric == nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The code builds successfully, but when I run the app and select a Metric from the list, the app freezes. If I pause the program execution in Xcode, this is the stack trace I get:

[image]

So, how can I make `@FocusedValue` work in this scenario, with an optional object from a list?

Comment: The crash is not because of optional bindings. Crash is probably because `.focusedValue(\.metricValue, selection)`  is set on the child view. Use a `@State` variable for the selection in the root view and pass it down to the child views as `@Binding`. In the root view set the `.focusedValue`.

Comment: I have used optional bindings and works fine when `.focusedValue` is set from the root view. (Xcode 13.0 (13A233) - macOS Big Sur 11.6)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Below is a View extension and ViewModifier that present a version of focusedValue which accepts an Binding to an optional. Not sure why this wasn't included in the framework as it corresponds more naturally to a selection situation in which there can be none...

```
extension View{
    func focusedValue<T>(_ keypath: WritableKeyPath<FocusedValues, Binding<T>?>, selection: Binding<T?>) -> some View{
        self.modifier(FocusModifier(keypath: keypath, optionalBinding: selection))
    }
}

struct FocusModifier<T>: ViewModifier{
    var keypath: WritableKeyPath<FocusedValues, Binding<T>?>
    var optionalBinding: Binding<T?>
    func body(content: Content) -> some View{
        Group{
            if optionalBinding.wrappedValue == nil{
                content
            }
            else if let binding = Binding(optionalBinding){
                content
                    .focusedValue(keypath, binding)
            }
            else{
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your car usage would look like:

```
    .focusedValue(\.metricValue, selection: $selection)
```

I have also found that the placement of this statement is finicky. I can only make things work when I place this on the NavigationView itself as opposed to one of its descendants (eg List).

Comment: Set the `.focusedValue` on the root view, create @State variable on the root view and pass it as bindings to the child view

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1 CoreData optional managedObject in @State var selection
@State var selection: Metric?

// 2 modifiers on View who own the list with the selection
.focusedValue(\.metricValue, $selection)
.focusedValue(\.deleteMetricAction) {
        if let metric = selection {
            print("Delete \(metric.name ?? "unknown metric")?")
        }
    }

// 3
extension FocusedValues {
    
    private struct SelectedMetricKey: FocusedValueKey {
        typealias Value = Binding<Metric?>
    }

    private struct DeleteMetricActionKey: FocusedValueKey {
        typealias Value = () -> Void
    }

    var metricValue: Binding<Metric?>? {
        get { self[SelectedMetricKey.self] }
        set { self[SelectedMetricKey.self] = newValue}
    }

    var deleteMetricAction: (() -> Void)? {
        get { self[DeleteMetricActionKey.self] }
        set { self[DeleteMetricActionKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

// 4 Use in macOS Monterey MenuCommands
struct MetricsCommands: Commands {

    @FocusedValue(\.metricValue) var selectedMetric
    @FocusedValue(\.deleteMetricAction) var deleteMetricAction

    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Type") {
            Button { deleteMetricAction?() } label: { Text("Delete \(selectedMetric.name ?? "unknown")") }.disabled(selectedMetric?.wrappedValue == nil || deleteMetricAction == nil )
         }
    }
}

// 5 In macOS @main App struct
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
    }
    .commands {
        SidebarCommands()
        MetricsCommands()
    }
}
```

[Use of @FocusedValues in Apple WWDC21 example](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10289)

[Use of FocusedValues in SwiftUI with Majid page](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2021/03/03/focusedvalue-and-focusedbinding-property-wrappers-in-swiftui/)

[Use of @FocusedSceneValue with example of action value passed, in Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/focusedscenevalue(_:_:))

Answer (score 0):

For SwiftUI 3 macOS Table who support multiple selections

```
// 1 Properties
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
var type: Type
var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Propriete>
var proprietes: FetchedResults<Propriete> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
@State private var selectedProprietes = Set<Propriete.ID>()

// 2 Init from Type managedObject who own Propriete managedObjects
// @FecthRequest required to have updates in Table (when delete for example)
init(type: Type) {
    self.type = type
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Propriete>(entity: Propriete.entity(),
                                           sortDescriptors: [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "nom",
                                                                               ascending: true,
                                                                               selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:))) ],
                                           predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", type))
}

// 3 Table view
VStack {
        Table(proprietes, selection: $selectedProprietes) {
            TableColumn("Propriétés :", value: \.wrappedNom)
        }
        .tableStyle(BorderedTableStyle())
        .focusedSceneValue(\.selectedProprietes, $selectedProprietes)
        .focusedSceneValue(\.deleteProprietesAction) {
            deleteProprietes(selectedProprietes)
        }
    }

// 4 FocusedValues
extension FocusedValues {

    private struct FocusedProprietesSelectionKey: FocusedValueKey {
        typealias Value = Binding<Set<Propriete.ID>>
    }

    var selectedProprietes: Binding<Set<Propriete.ID>>? {
        get { self[FocusedProprietesSelectionKey.self] }
        set { self[FocusedProprietesSelectionKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

// 5 Delete (for example) in Table View
private func deleteProprietes(_ proprietesToDelete: Set<Propriete.ID>) {
    var arrayToDelete = [Propriete]()
    for (index, propriete) in proprietes.enumerated() {
        if proprietesToDelete.contains(propriete.id) {
            let propriete = proprietes[index]
            arrayToDelete.append(propriete)
        }
    }
    if arrayToDelete.count > 0 {
        print("array to delete: \(arrayToDelete)")
        for item in arrayToDelete {
            context.delete(item)
            print("\(item.wrappedNom) deleted!")
        }
        try? context.save()
    }
}
```

[How to manage selection in Table](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table)